# NSCollectionViewItems shaking and with X to remove

Tags: objective-c, macos, nscollectionview

On Launchpad we have basically a big collection view with app icons. When you hold an app (press down with the cursor and don't stop) for a very long time, all the icons start to shake, and a little 'x' appears in the top left hand corner of each one of them, which makes removing items very easy.

I would like to know if there is some method already implemented in the API which allow us to reproduce that same behavior in a regular NSCollectionView.

I've checked `NSCollectionView` and `NSCollectionViewDelegate` documentations in Apple's Mac Developer Library, however I haven't seeing anything related to that. Should that be done *manually*? If so, how can I make the collection view items shake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no existing method to do this, but you can recreate it with Core Animation.

Providing the full code to do that is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow (and would be highly dependent on your existing code), but a `CABasicAnimation` affecting the `transform.rotation` key of the layers of your `NSCollectionViewItem` views should put you on the right path.

Comment: Yeah, agree about the full code parth; I just wanted exactly what you just said :)